# Remove padding from inline code created with CodeMirror

Tags: javascript, css, codemirror

I'm implementing [CodeMirror](http://codemirror.net/) on a project and need to use it to syntax highlight both code blocks and inline code.

Here's a sample I've put together to demonstrate what I'm trying to do: http://students.susanbuck.net/storage/code/code-mirror/

The syntax is working in both instances, but where I'm stuck is finding a way to kill the padding only on the `.inline` code elements so they don't add excess space between the lines in the paragraph.

Comment: You can override any inline styles by targeting the respective elements in your CSS file and adding the `!important` declaration

Comment: Problem comes in when trying to distinguish between the block and inline code boxes. It's complex because of how many divs CodeMirror generates. Simply targeting .inline isn't working.

Comment: You can see in the HTML that the `.CodeMirror` divs are added straight after the `textarea` elements - so you can just target the elements that follow teaxareas with the `.inline` class. I have added an answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to target the `.CodeMirror-lines` divs that follow `textarea.code.inline` elements. This can be achieved using the following CSS selector:

```
textarea.code.inline + div.CodeMirror div.CodeMirror-lines {
    padding: 0px!important; /* added !important as padding is an inline stlye */
}
```

There is also a height value set in a child of `div.CodeMirror-scroll` that you might want to avoid. You can make this height redundent by using the following CSS:

```
textarea.code.inline + div.CodeMirror > div.CodeMirror-scroll { 
    max-height: 1em;
}
```

Comment: Excellent. I wasn't hitting the right combinations in my attempt to target that div; this works great.